# How to execute SQL scripts (SQL Dacpac file) in Azure Data Factory v2?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to create SQL tables in the Azure SQL Database and then load the data to those tables from CSV files in the Blob storage. The tables needs to created and then dropped after the completion of process.

We usually use the dacpac to deploy the database objects from Azure Devops pipeline.
Is there a way to execute these dacpac from ADF? 
or Is there any activity in the Azure Data Factory v2 to execute the scripts, if I maintain these scripts in the storage?

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Per my experience, I'm afraid we can't do. Data factory doesn't support create table from bacpac file.

Comment: Hi MBK, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you and have a good weekend!

Comment: Hello MBK, if you have any other concerns, please let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I know about Data Factory, we can not import the DACPAC file to SQL database directly.

Data Factory will consider the dacpac as a file, not a SQL script.

And Azure Data Factory only supports the following file formats. Refer to each article for format-based settings.:
[image]

Hope this helps.